# Aliases to mutable thread-local data not allowed

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, alias, d

I'm new to D and I'm writing a simple multithreaded server for practice. A common paradigm for starting client handler threads in C is to pass the file descriptor of the newly-accept()ed socket into pthread_create(), but D's std.concurrency.spawn() will not allow me to pass the Socket because it's mutable and accessible by two threads.

Of course, I don't actually want an immutable socket (which is why I don't really want to cast it in the main thread unless I have to) - I want to pass a mutable one in and have it go out of scope in the main thread. How would I go about this? Should(/can) I use `tid.send(s)` to let the thread use the socket? For some reason that seems very clunky to me.

My code now:

```
void main() {
    Socket listener = new TcpSocket;
    ...
    for (;;) {
        Socket s = listener.accept();
        scope(exit) s.close();

        auto tid = spawn(&clientHandler, s);
    }
}

void clientHandler(Socket s) {
    ...
}
```

Which produces: Error: static assert  "Aliases to mutable thread-local data not allowed." ... instantiated from here: spawn!(Socket)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to cast the socket to shared and back again in the clienthandler

```
auto tid = spawn(&clientHandler, cast(shared) s);

void clientHandler(shared Socket s) {
    Socket sock = cast(Socket)s;
    scope(exit)sock.close();
}
```

the reason for this is that all local variables are implicitly thread local unless specified `shared`, and only references to shared or immutable can be passed as argument to `spawn` (or `send`) while stuff passed by value (structs without references and primitives) is fine

also you should put the close int the handler as with your current implementation the socket will likely be closed before the newly spawned thread has a chance to run

Comment: Worked perfectly, and thanks for the additional info! Is this the idiomatic way to do something like this, or is there some better way? Casting in D feels decidedly like I'm doing something wrong (ie as opposed to C).

Comment: @Dan last I checked (a year ago) `shared`'s semantics where not well defined, I don't know if that changed since then

Comment: Nothing changed with regards to that. But the whole D community is waiting for `shared` to become well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here isn't the socket, which is a local variable. It's the clientHandler, whose declaration you haven't shown, but clearly it is thread-local as it says in the error message, when there should be a new one per accepted socket. The hint is the word 'alias', which refers to the & operator.

Comment: Sorry, I've clarified the question by adding the declaration of `clientHandler()`. It's a function declared in global scope, so perhaps I'm more confused than I originally thought, but I doubt it is the thread-local data in question.

Comment: @Dan Ok, so what is? Not the socket, unless scope() has some effect on that, whatever it does: I am no 'd' expert.

Comment: `scope(exit)` ensures that `s.close()` will be called at the end of this scope, much like the `finally` keyword in Java. Admittedly, it doesn't make a ton of sense where I added it, but removing it or placing it elsewhere has no effect on the compilation error. I read that [global variables](http://dlang.org/migrate-to-shared.html) are automatically converted into thread-locals, but that should not apply to functions, and at any rate replacing the function alias with a (local, I think) lambda expression results in the same error as well.

Comment: Also note, if I replace the `Socket` argument to `clientHandler()` with a `string` (strings are immutable), this compiles fine. I think that local variable is getting promoted to a thread-local variable!